# Query with sum and inner join not working

Tags: sql-server, sum

I don't know why this SQL query does not work correctly, it returns the same records without summing using the `sum` function

```
select      *, sum(VenteProduit.MontantHT) as 'TOTAL HT' 
from        RegFacture 
inner join  VenteProduit 
        on  RegFacture.NumFacture = VenteProduit.NumFacture  
group by  VenteProduit.NumFacture, 
          RegFacture.NumFacture, 
          RegFacture.DateFacture, 
          RegFacture.ModePaiment, 
          RegFacture.DateEcheance, 
          RegFacture.TVA, 
          RegFacture.Devise, 
          RegFacture.MontantPayee,
          RegFacture.RestMontant,
          RegFacture.LieuLivraison,
          RegFacture.incoterm,
          RegFacture.Unite,
          VenteProduit.RsClient,
          VenteProduit.RefProduit,
          VenteProduit.PrixVente,
          VenteProduit.Quantitee,
          VenteProduit.MontantHT
```

[image: it returns the same records the result should be 2100]

Comment: you are `group by` every single column in the `select`. remove all other columns except `MontantHT` from the `select` and `group by`

Comment: 1) I highly recommend learning to use aliases in your queries they will make it far more readable. 2) You appear to be grouping by every column in the query, so you will get a result for each row with no aggregation and therefore no sum. In SQL Server you can't select every column *and* aggregate at the same time. If you wish to do that you need a window function.

Comment: @Mohamed - why did you undo the formatting I applied to your query? Its unreadable now?

Comment: sorry I modified the code because I want to display all the columns of the tables in inner join mode, but the Sum () function does not work for each Numfacture

Comment: Well please format it again

Comment: I want to display all the records, that's why I modified the code which contains Where in select

Comment: ok thank you a lot

Comment: the problem is solved using window function, thank you a lot @Dale K  ` select *,sum(VenteProduit.MontantHT) OVER(PARTITION BY VenteProduit.NumFacture) as 'TOTAL HT' FROM [dbo].VenteProduit    inner join  RegFacture on RegFacture.NumFacture=VenteProduit.NumFacture
`

Comment: I have formatted your query for you. For your information, adding `space` to separate the column names, make its more readable and does not impact your query performance

Comment: @Mohamed in that case either post your answer as a solution (self answer) or just delete your question.

Comment: @Dale the answer is done thank you

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved using window function

the new query is:

```
select *,sum(VenteProduit.MontantHT) OVER(PARTITION BY VenteProduit.NumFacture) as 'TOTAL HT' 
FROM [dbo].VenteProduit 
inner join RegFacture on RegFacture.NumFacture=VenteProduit.NumFacture
```